# Can all functions $f:{\mathbb R}^N\to{\mathbb R}^M$ be written as $(f_1(x_1,...x_N), ... f_M(x_1,...x_N))$?

Tags: functions, proof-writing, vectors

Can any function that outputs an array be rewriten as an array of functions that output a number? I don't know of any functions that would violate this but I don't know how to proove it either.

Comment: Formally, yes, but it will not always be possible to determine the functions for the components explicitely. In other words, closed forms will not always exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, because you can define each of those functions $f_i$ as $f_i(x_1, .. ,x_n)=id^m_i(f(x_1,...,x_n))$

In general, $id^n_i$ is the (projection) function that out of $n$ arguments returns the $i$-th argument out of $n$ arguments. That is, $id^n_i(x_1,...,x_n)=x_i$

Answer (score 2):

Short answer : yes.

Long answer :

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^N\mapsto \mathbb{R}^M$ we want to build a $(f_i)_{i\in[1,N]}$ with $\forall i, f_i : \mathbb{R}^n\mapsto \mathbb{R}$ that satifies your condition.

Let's note $f(x)=y, y\in \mathbb{R}^M$ with $y = \begin{pmatrix}y_{1}\\y_{2}\\...\\y_{M} \end{pmatrix}$

Then we see that we can easily build $f_i$ :

$$\forall i \in [1,M], f_i(x) = y_{i}$$

Now we got

$$\forall x\in \mathbb{R}^N, f(x) = \begin{pmatrix}y_{1}\\y_{2}\\...\\y_{M} \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}f_1(x)\\f_2(x)\\...\\f_M(x) \end{pmatrix}$$

You might want to look at [this article about projections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_(mathematics))